# How can the playback button on YouTube videos, be eliminated during playback?

Tags: raspbian, video, web-browsers

On Raspbian OS, Epiphany browser, the video plays fine, even the sound is in sync, on a Pi 2, however that nasty play button (centered on the screen in white & red )never disappears.

Comment: Is this a single video or general YouTube viewing? I would download single video and run it as a local file. For YouTube viewing I would opt for the chromium browser which contains the open source bits of Google Chrome.

Comment: Every video, except music videos, on YouTube, work perfect; load time with my Pi2 is actually as fast as any windows or mac box.  As incredible as that seems, after employing my tactics referred to in "Epiphany Browser is unable to display HTML5 Video" on this site.  So, do you know Rob, will the Chromium browser play YouTube music videos  ?

Comment: Its not something I can check at the moment but it does point to a DRM/piracy/AD issue implemented by Google as it only affects music videos. There is no harm in sudo apt-get install chromium and giving it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this myself. If I'm not mistaken, Epiphany uses a hack behind the scenes to get the YouTube video to play. It is part of this hack and not the YouTube player itself that causes that play button to sit there forever.

I considered modifying the JavaScript it uses to try and get the button to go away, but I'm trying to see if there's a much better way around it.

You can see the code in /usr/share/epiphany-browser in some files named hack-* . If you're familiar with JavaScript, you can probably edit the EmbedLoader.prototype.startVideo function and add a line that says

> this.playArea.style.display='none';

right after the

> this.playArea.style.opacity = 0;

line or something similar to have it disappear ("playArea" is the element for the play button). It looks like it tries to use some opacity effects to hide it, and probably if those don't work, it ends up just staying there.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Turns out it's like comparing Black & White to Color TV ! I realised I was using the wrong tool for the job; The OpenElec operating system is SO much more efficient for YOUTUBE videos.  Listening to music vids on YT is as simple as installing the pre-configured plug-in and selecting your video ! ADDED ADVANTAGES: OpenElec has a newer OS configured to take advantage of the newest Pi2....This will allow you to pump out music from BOTH your HDMI port & sound port (3.5mm) simultaneously IN SYNC. However, AirPlay (preconfigured) is the game changer !  Please see my post: Open Elec phantom screen!

Comment: Post Script: No More Playback button !